# How to use mtpro2 together with other math-font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, font-encodings, mtpro

for example, load `mtpro2` and `XITS-Math` for different paragraph

But it seems, `mtpro2` und `unicode-math` can not be loaded together

Error like:

```
LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \notsimeq already defined.
```

My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}  

\usepackage{unicode-math} % to use \setmathfont

\begin{document}
    Source Serif Pro $f=|a|/3$ with mtpro2 \\

  {\setmathfont[StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
    Source Serif Pro $f=|a|/3$ with XITS Math}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you load `unicode-math` you give up with legacy math management.

Answer (score 2):

To use a legacy math font such as `mtpro2` with a TrueType or OpenType text font, load `mathspec` rather than `unicode-math`.